# To change color on onclick event using react

Tags: reactjs

I need to change the colour of a `div` tag which I have designed when it is clicked. I need to change the colour of the `div` and I need to add a `class` to the `div` when it is clicked, which I need answer in react

Comment: Could you support your claims with a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi Jerald! As @ParthS007 suggested, it would be really nice if you attach a piece of your code (even if it's not working), so we can help you find out what you are looking for. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you have any trouble.

Comment: Sir thanks for your help the below code help me to to do that what I want anyway thank you parths007 and Michalis Garganouraiis

Answer (score 2):

Like others mentioned, a little more code details would be nice from your side.

One of the ways to achieve what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/hawk939393/Ly0912nf/

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    divClicked: false
  };

  getClassname = () => {
    return !this.state.divClicked ? 
      "toDoApp" : "toDoApp-isClicked"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.getClassname()}
        onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => ({divClicked: !prevState.divClicked}))}>
        Hello world!
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

^ Have a state that tracks whether a `div`'s `className` has been changed.